# C++ OpenMP computation errors with private and shared clause

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I have a `for` loop to be parallelized with OpenMP, but there are multiple computational errors, probably due to my lack of understanding of the concept of multithreading with OpenMP:

```
for ( int i = -X/2; i < X/2; ++i )
{
    base.y = anchor + i*rho_step;
    temp = some_function( base );
    if( temp > response )
    {
        buffer.y = base.y;
        response = temp;
    }
}
```

This works fine, then I made the following changes:

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared (buffer, response) private(base, temp)
for ( int i = -X/2; i < X/2; ++i )
{
    base.y = anchor + i*rho_step;
    temp = some_function( base );
    if( temp > response )
    {
        buffer.y = base.y;
        response = temp;
    }
}
```

In this code, neither `buffer.y` nor `response` will have the correct values. In my understanding, every single thread should have an own copy of `base.y` and `temp`, they are only temporary variables for the computation, and `buffer` and `response` must be shared (they will store the computed data), but this does not work as I would expect.

The only version that is perfect is the following, but obviously, there is no performance increase:

```
omp_lock_t writelock;
omp_init_lock(&writelock);
omp_set_num_threads (4);

#pragma omp parallel for
for ( int i = -X/2; i < X/2; ++i )
{
    omp_set_lock(&writelock);
    base.y = anchor + i*rho_step;
    temp = some_function( base );
    if( temp > response )
    {
        buffer.y = base.y;
        response = temp;
    }
    omp_unset_lock(&writelock);
}
omp_destroy_lock(&writelock);
```

What can be the problem? (`anchor` and `rho_step` are constants in this loop)

Comment: To me, it looks like there is a data dependency: `response` may change and influences directly later loop passes. If so, you cannot accelerate the loop easily using any multithreading tool. Only if `some_function` needs a lot of time, it would be usefull to add multithreading.

Comment: `response` changes only in case of the if condition is true. The some_function does relatively a lot of stuff, that's why I tried to save running time. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get your code to deal with the trans-thread of the `buffer` and `response` variables, you'll need to use some per-thread local variables for them, and perform a final reduction with them to update their shared counterparts.

Here is what it would look like (not tested):

```
#pragma omp parallel firstprivate( base )
{
    auto localResponse = response;
    auto localBuffer = buffer;
    #pragma omp for
    for ( int i = -X/2; i < X/2; ++i )
    {
        base.y = anchor + i * rho_step;
        auto temp = some_function( base );
        if ( temp > localResponse )
        {
            localBuffer.y = base.y;
            localResponse = temp;
        }
    }
    #pragma omp critical
    {
        if ( localResponse > response )
        {
            buffer.y = localBuffer.y;
            response = localResponse;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this produced the same result. I can't see why we need the per-thread local variables if `buffer` and `response` are shared and are in a critical section. For every different `i` we have different `base.y` and `temp`, and we only have to manage that each thread has own `base.y`-s and `temp`-s, and check if they have to modify `buffer` and `response` one-by-one.
(Sorry for my imperfect knowledge.)

Comment: I just made one change by putting `base` `firstprivate` since it isn't clear whether the other fields are significant in the context. Anyway, the point of my method is that the final reduction (the `critical` section) is outside of the parallel loop, but inside the parallel section. It occurs only once at the end, not at every iteration like in your code...

Comment: The `firstprivate` solved the problem, now both your and my version works, thank you!

Comment: Be careful though that your version suffers from a race condition for variables `buffer` and `response` (this is the whole point of making local versions and doing a final reduction in a `critical` section). So although your version seems to work with `firstprivate`, it is essentially wrong.